# Spring logs are writing , where as Normal logs not writing using log4j

Tags: java, xml, spring, logging

I am Using Log4j.xml for logging for my system , I ave two projects , oneis a spring project and another is a normal java project ,

I have log4j.xml configured for both projcts , the pblm is , only spring injected logs are getting written in log file , and the normal java logs is not getting written in log file , can u help me what is the exact pblm , and where am i doing wrong??

log4j.xml 
`

```
    <appender name="scoringenine.trace" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/logs/scoringengine/Trace.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d | %5p %X{SessionID} %t %n %l : %m  %n%n%n" /> 
        </layout>
        </appender>  
    <appender name="util.trace" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/logs/util/Util.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d | %5p %X{SessionID} %t %n %l : %m  %n%n%n" /> 
        </layout>
        </appender>
<category name="com.core" additivity="true">
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="scoringenine.trace"/>
    </category> 
<category name="com.util" additivity="true">
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="util.trace"/>
    </category>
```

`

web.xml
`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/config/spring/applicationcontext.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

`spring.xml`

```
<bean id="mqLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-method="getLogger">
        <constructor-arg value="com.*.mq"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

`

> My java

`

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    Class Utils{
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName());
    logger.log("inside utils");
    }
```

`

> i have log4j , slflog4j , commons-lang.jar in my classpath
>   This looger is not printing (Util.log) util.trace, appender not logging in log file , where as spring injected logs (Trace.log) scorengine.trace appender are logging...

Comment: http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2010/05/how-to-configure-log4j-for-a-web-app/

Comment: You may find something in this link http://www.tech423ppl.com/2014/02/configuring-log4j-with-websphere-v-51.html

Answer (score 0):

LogFactory is a Apache Commons Logging factory, since a different framework. You need to instanciate you logger like this:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Utils.class);
```

Make sure you have defined this import:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Comment: Hi @Stefan , Sorry , i have did the same way u told , still its not writing

Comment: Did you log with LOG.info("abc")?

Comment: hi @Stefan , sorry , I am using Log.info("") only